# PHP - Conciliação bancária

Tags: php, boleto, zend-framework-2

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que necessitará da funcionalidade de conciliação bancária.

Para isso, deverá ser usado o padrão cnab 400, para o Banco do Brasil.
Eu preciso gerar o arquivo-remessa e tratar o arquivo-retorno. Contudo, não assimilei bem como deverá ser esse processo.

Para o Banco do Brasil não consegui encontrar tutorial ou algo do tipo para me orientar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste repositório e faça alguns testes com seu arquivo de retorno para ver se funciona como esperado: https://github.com/manoelcampos/Retorno-BoletoPHP

Answer (score 5):

O *Banco do Brasil* vai disponibilizar para você todo dia um arquivo de retorno com a baixa dos boletos realizadas no dia anterior (as vezes mais antigos), através do internet banking. 
O arquivo de retorno é um arquivo de texto normal, se eu não me engando com a extensão .ret. Ele funciona da seguinte forma, a primeira linha é o cabeçalho (Registro Header) e contem os dados da conta e a finalidade daquele arquivo, a ultima é o Registro Trailler do arquivo e só registra o final do mesmo, o restante do arquivo (Registro Detalhe) representa os registros ocorridos, pode representar baixa, liquidação, protesto, entre outras.
Para saber o que cada campo do arquivo representa, você tem que dar uma lida no manual do banco.
Acesse o link [Manual BB](http://www.bb.com.br/portalbb/page44,3766,18879,0,0,1,2.bb) aqui tem todos os manuais, o que você precisa é o  [CBR643 (CNAB400)](http://www.bb.com.br/docs/pub/emp/empl/dwn/Doc2628CBR643Pos7.pdf).

Fique atento porque mesmo não ocorrendo registro, o BB gera o arquivo de retorno vazio, sem Registro Detalhe.

Comment: Oi, em que seção do internet banking eu posso enviar o arquivo de remessa e verificar se recebi o arquivo de retorno ?

Comment: Se eu não me engano é TRANSMISSÃO DE ARQUIVO ou TRANSFERÊNCIA DE ARQUIVOS